# If() function and delegates in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates, conditional-operator

Taking the following code in VB2012, I expect foo to be initialized to Nothing:

```
 Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = If(True, Nothing, Function() 0)
```

However, it throws an ArgumentException:

```
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
```

I don't quite understand this error message, but the situation gets outright scary if I change the type of foo to Func(Of Integer, Integer). In that case the code runs with no errors, but foo gets to be a mysterious lambda expression, which throws a NullReferenceException when called.

If I use the traditional If statement instead of the If function, the code works as expected.

Could someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: Compiler bug.  Present in VS2013, you can file it at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant: Also 2010 and 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `IIf` works just fine:

```
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = IIf(True, Nothing, Function() 0)
```

But I have to say, I have no idea why.

***Update***

OK, I think I have a reason. Compiler optimizes your code to following:

```
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = New Func(Of Integer)(Nothing.Invoke)
```

and that's why you get an exception.

Even when you don't use `True` as condition, and try to use variable

```
Dim t = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) < 10
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = If(t, Nothing, Function() 0)
```

it's being transformed into:

```
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = New Func(Of Integer)((If((Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) < 10), Nothing, New VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Integer)(Nothing, ldftn(_Lambda$__1)))).Invoke)
```

which will throw exception anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I suspected that error will be `there is no implicit conversion between Nothing and lambda`.

Comment: So is this a bug in the VB compiler? Because I still don't see why my code would be wrong.

Comment: Problem occurs because of a way compiler transforms you `If()` statement. I'm not sure if it's a bug or it's documented somewhere, but I think it's not really intuitive and I would expect it to work,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in compiler, because this code is equivalent, but it works as expected:

```
Dim f As Func(Of Integer) = Function() 0
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = If(True, Nothing, f)
```

I was also able to reproduce your *mysterious lambda expression* using this code:

```
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = If(True, Nothing, Function() Nothing)
```

Which is logically equivalent to your statement (`Nothing` should get implicitly converted to `0`).

This is weird - if compiler wants to optimize something, I would expect it to optimize in the same way as it would do for below statement. However, the below statement behaves as expected:

```
Dim foo As Func(Of Integer) = If(True, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Because `True` is always `True`, both this statement and yours should result in the same code.